# Blogger Page Layouts depending on Page Type

Tags: xml, blogger, blogspot

Hello everyone? I am new on here and hope you guys can help me out with a problem I have. I'm creating a blogger template and what I wanna do is show a post's first image, an excerpt and a read more button on the home page. I have succeeded in doing that. The problem is that nothing shows up when I try to show the posts Heading, and entire post content on post page. Please help me out

```
    <b:includable id='main'>
        <!-- Return this on Home Page Only -->
       <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
          <b:loop var='i' values='data:posts'>
              <!-- Get Post Tile -->
              <h2><data:i.title/></h2>
              <!-- If there is an image or Images in the post, get the first one -->
              <b:if cond='data:i.firstImageUrl'>
                 <img expr:src ="data:i.firstImageUrl" expr:alt="data:post.title"/><br/>
              </b:if>
              <!-- Get Snippet of the Post -->
                <data:i.snippet /><br/>
              <!-- Display a readmore Button -->
              <a expr:href='data:i.url'><button>Read More</button></a>   
          </b:loop>
       </b:if>
        <!-- Return this on item/Posts page only -->
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
            <h3><data:post.title/></h3>
            <data:post.body/>

        </b:if>
    </b:includable>
 </b:widget>
```

Nothing shows up on the item page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loop` for post is missing for `item` page. Try this code

```
    <!-- Return this on item/Posts page only -->
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "item"'>
        <b:loop var='i' values='data:posts'>
            <h3><data:i.title/></h3>
            <data:i.body/>
        </b:loop>
    </b:if>
```

Comment: Thanks simr, this worked perfectly. One more question, that is the same loop I used for the index page, how comes on the index page it returns all the posts but on the item page it returns one specific post. Thank again